# Java Process Decode Repository getById

Tags: java, spring, repository-pattern, dto

I'm having a repository and a DTO (lets call it DataDTO)
inside that DTO I'm having a field - `link` (with getter and setter)

```
public class DataDTO {
   private String link;

   @JsonProperty(value = "link")
   Public String getLink() {
      return link
   }

   public void setLink(String value) {
      link = value;
   }
}
```

I need to decode the `link` property for the client using:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;

...

URLDecoder.decode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The thing is that it's done in multiple (a lot) of controllers.

I can do it in every controller (Actually it's in a service the controller calls):

```
   ...
   DataDTO dataDTO = dataRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
   if (dataDTO) {
      dataDTO.setLink(URLDecoder.decode(dataDTO.getLink(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   }
```

But I'm trying to find a more generic approach to that.

Thought about doing that inside the getter:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "link")
Public String getLink() {
   return URLDecoder.decode(link, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)   
}
```

But generally I'm not sure if adding a logic inside the DTO is a good practice.

Thought about maybe if it's possible to extend the `getById` repository function to return the value decoded and this way keeping the DTO logic-free.

How you would do it?

Would like to hear if anyone have any suggestion or better practice to do some processing on the DTO? in the repository level? in the DTO level? in the service level? in a util? in the controller?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the repository should return pure data.
2. There is no objection to putting logic in dto. Because the object must have autonomy, and the object that has data is dto.But in your case, it's different.

If I were in the same situation as you, I would create another object that would lap a link string.

```java
public class MyLink {

  private String link;

  public String getLink() {
        URLDecoder.decode (this.link, StandardCharsets).UTF_8);   
  }
}
```

The advantage of this is that when you use MyLink objects to obtain link data, you can always force yourself to obtain decoded url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute Converter for auto conversion when data fetch from database and when store also.

Create an Attribute Converter

```
public class LinkAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return URLDecoder.decode(dbData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }
}
```

And use on field of entity

```
@Convert(converter = LinkAttributeConverter.class)
private String link;
```

So, when you fetch using repository then link automatically converted